# StructureMap resolve generic instance based on Type dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

Is there a way to resolve based on Type?

```
Type t = typeof(Person);
var test = Container.Current.TryGetInstance(IMapper<t, ViewModel>);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

[.NET generics: how to resolve type T in run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527486/net-generics-how-to-resolve-type-t-in-run-time)

```
Type p = typeof(Person);
Type vm = typeof(ViewModel);

var concreteHandlerType = typeof(IMapper<,>).MakeGenericType(p, vm);
var handler = Container.Current.GetInstance(concreteHandlerType);
```

Container registration:

```
c.For(typeof(IMapper<,>)).Use(typeof(Mapper<,>));
```